# SQL - Selecting columns from different tables without common columns

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables which I need to extract the data from and they have no common data. Here's an example of both tables.

Eg1 and Ie1 are examples of the column name.

asd and afd are examples of the data.

**Table 1**

```
Eg1 | Eg2 | Eg3 | Eg4 | Eg5
asd | wer | weq | qwe | wtp
```

**Table 2**

```
Ie1 | Ie2 | Ie3 | Ie4 | Ie5
afd | ehd | xva | nbv | sdf
```

1. How can I retrieve Eg2, and Ie2 data and put them side by side?

Expected out put would be -

```
Eg2 | Ie2
wer | ehd
```

2. How can I retrieve the same data from the same table twice? (Example output would be displaying 2  columns of Ie3)

This part of the question should be solved using the ALIAS (?)

Expected output would be -

```
Ie3 | Ie3
xva | xva
```

Comment: What is Eg1, etc? Column names?   Please show sample data for each, and expected output.  If they have no relationship, how can you expect to join them?

Comment: @OldProgrammer yup they are the column names. My thoughts exactly, I was thrown with this 2 tables and the output I desired are basically what I'm told to do. Confused.

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: show the output for two records in each table

Comment: @JavaDevil I'm using SQL developer

Comment: @Igor i've already included in the question. I will add a few more rows if required/

Comment: show the output for two records in the first table and three records in the second table

Comment: Is there a common column (primary key / foreign key) between these tables or are you just pairing up every row?

Comment: Why do you want to pick two completely unrelated items using a JOIN? (Do a UNION ALL instead.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
SELECT 
    EG1, 
    IE1 
FROM TABLE1,
     TABLE2
```

This will result in every possible combination of the two, As seen on this [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/eb43ec/1)

And for second part use

```
SELECT 
    IE3, 
    IE3 
FROM TABLE2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can sure select them, but it will depend on how the data is in the DB and you have no way of actually knowing what the final result row will contain.

```
    SELECT a.Eg2,b.Ie2 FROM a,b
```

a and b are your table name.

Also

```
   SELECT b.Ie3,b.Ie3
   FROM b
```

is valid as well.

Comment: As @Java-Devil point out this **This will result is every possible combination of the two** is going to happen.